# In the UK, does a person have the right to refuse a police "Stop and Search"

Tags: united-kingdom, police

UK Police's stop and search powers have been talked about a lot in the news in recent months.

I would like to know if an individual has the right to refuse a stop and search by police in the UK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

**No**

The primary stop and search powers are at:

- [s.1 of the Police and Criminal Evidence Act](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1984/60/section/1?timeline=false)
- [s.23 of the Misuse of Drugs Act 1971](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1971/38/section/23?timeline=false)
- [s.47
  of the Firearms Act 1968](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1968/27/section/47?timeline=false)

which all empower an officer to detain a person for the purposes of that search.

Resisting a search may well be an offence under [s.89(2) of the Police Act 1996](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1996/16/section/89?timeline=false):

> Any person who resists or wilfully obstructs a constable in the execution of his duty [...] shall be guilty of an offence and liable on summary conviction to imprisonment for a term not exceeding one month or to a fine not exceeding level 3 on the standard scale, or to both.